# Convert a collection-typed annotation from Java to Scala

Tags: scala, annotations

Following is an annotation from java

```
import com.beust.jcommander._

@Parameter(names = {"-hzcfg", "--hzConfig"}, description = "Configuration file")
private String hzCfg = "config/hz-config.xml";
```

How do we convert the ***names*** collection to Scala? Here was my attempt:

class SparkBenchmarkArguments {

```
@Parameter(names = {"-hzcfg", "--hzConfig"}, description = "Configuration file")
val hzCfg = "config/hz-config.xml"
```

}

Here are the compilation error

> Error:(28, 33) ';' expected but ',' found.
>     @Parameter(names = {"-hzcfg", "--hzConfig"}, description = "Configuration file")
>
> Error:(29, 13) expected start of definition
>     private String hzCfg = "config/hazelcast-config.xml"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala equivalent turns out to be to use an explicit Array as follows:

> @Parameter(names = **Array**("-hzcfg", "--hzConfig"), description =
>   "Configuration file")

Comment: `{ x, y }` is an explicit array in Java.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral  Point well taken  - so the above represents  the simple translation of the java array to a scala array.